# C2280: "attempting to reference deleted function" for copy constructor, CC248 "'operator ='cannot access private member declared in class" (Cocos2dx)

Tags: c++, oop, vector, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a question regarding creating a 2D vector of objects during instantiation of an object.

**Background:** I have a class called Dungeon which needs a 2D vector of Tile objects. (Vector because I can resize since until instantiation I don't know the dimensions of the vector.)

**Error:**

```
Error   C2280   'Tile &Tile::operator =(const Tile &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  MyCppGame   c:\users\dante\git\yshacpp\mycppgame\classes\tile.cpp   18
```

UPDATE: Now I am receiving
`Error  C2248   'cocos2d::Sprite::operator =': cannot access private member declared in class 'cocos2d::Sprite'` -- Could it be a cocos2D-X issue with Sprite's `operator=`? Putting Sprite declarations in `public` didn't help but I'm suspecting something with cocos2D-X....

**My suspicion (revised):** `cocos2d::Sprite* floor, item, overlay, ceiling;` inside my `Tile` class seems to cause this error to be thrown.

**What I've tried:** Writing my own copy constructor for Tile.

---

Maybe my suspicions are wrong, but if anyone could let me know why this is happening I'd be grateful!

---

**CPP file of class (Tile)**

```
#include "Tile.h"

Tile::Tile()  : block(false), hasCharacter(false) { /* Nothing */ }
```

**Header file of class Tile**

```
#ifndef __TILE_H__
#define __TILE_H__

#include ...

class Tile {
protected:
    bool deepCopy(const Tile& copyTile) {
        bool result = false;
        if (&copyTile != this) {
            this->character = copyTile.character;
            this->floor = copyTile.floor;
            this->item = copyTile.item;
            this->overlay = copyTile.overlay;
            this->ceiling = copyTile.ceiling;
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    cocos2d::Sprite* floor, item, overlay, ceiling;

// private: // nothing atm
public:
    bool block, hasCharacter;
    Character character;

    Tile();
    Tile(const Tile& copyTile) { deepCopy(copyTile); };
    Tile& operator=(const Tile& copyTile) { deepCopy(copyTile); return *this; }
    //~Tile();
};

#endif // __TILE_H__
```

Comment: You can't have a vector of non-copyable non-movable objects, because vector needs to copy the objects (or move them).

Comment: `operator =` is the assignment operator, not copy constructor

Comment: probably `Character` is non-copyable, so `Tile`'s implicit assignment operator is deleted

Comment: `Tile` owning a pointer to another `Tile` is pretty bizarre

Comment: Hi @M.M, thanks for the responses. I accidentally deleted my comment (said I couldn't edit after 5 minutes but you had already replied). 

So to address those two points you mentioned:
- Make Character copyable
- Not use "=" operator in Tile constructor, but rather copy constructor

...? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It's not clear why Tile has `ptr`. Can you explain why every tile "contains" another tile"

Comment: @M.M I thought that it was necessary to allocate the memory before reassigning it to point to a new Tile during copying. But this feels incorrect and I must be going in the wrong direction...

Comment: Question edited with more information. It seems not to be "Character" but instantiating Tile with lots of `cocos2d::Sprite*` pointers. Which leads me to think that "Tile" needs a "deep copy," so I will try that. (Possibly `cocos2d::Sprite` is what needs the deep copy...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time around I noticed that cocos2d classes were acting up in Visual Studio (Community 2015), so I confirmed that `import "cocos2d.h"` was not working. That turned out to be the problem.

---

So to recap, I made the following changes:

1) Made sure my IDE was including the header file properly (Visual Studio Community 2015)

2) Edited `Tile.h`:

```
class Tile { ...
private:
    cocos2d::Sprite* floor;
    cocos2d::Sprite* item;
    cocos2d::Sprite* overlay;
    cocos2d::Sprite* ceiling
...
}
```

3) Rewrote my deep copy

and then it worked.

It's a strange situation but for what it's worth, I removed my Deep Copy to see what would happen and it works without it. If it's best practice to have it, I will keep it there....

Thanks to everyone who took their time out to comment since it helped clarify a lot of mistakes that I was making.

---

P.S. If anyone thinks this question should be deleted as it is misleading please let me know.